# Redirecting output to a file and getting I/O error

Tags: python, redirect

I am trying to redirect output to the file

Below code works fine

```
import sys
print('###################################Genarating Global     Variables##########################')
storage_file = open("Storage-output.txt", 'w')
sys.stdout = storage_file
print ('whatever')
storage_file.close()
```

Below code is not working:

```
  import sys
  print('###################################Genarating Global Variables##########################')
  storage_file = open("Storage-output.txt", 'w')
  sys.stdout = storage_file
  print ('what')
  storage_file.close()
  print('Completed Global variables creation')
```

Basically what I need is, some of print output should go to file and some of print output should display in terminal. For that I am planning to open file and closing file whenever required in script.

Comment: In what way is this "not working?" Please copy and past the I/O error message into the question. Are you using any redirection such as `>` or `|` on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is self-explained:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "something.py", line 7, in <module>
   print('Completed Global variables creation')
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

You assign your file handler to stdout: `sys.stdout = storage_file`, but closed `storage_file` before the last `print`, which caused this problem. If you want last `print` to work like the first line again, you need to re-assign `sys.stdout` to its original value, by the way, when dealing with file, always consider to use `with` statement:

```
    import sys

    print('###################################Genarating Global Variables##########################')
    stdout = sys.stdout
    with open("Storage-output.txt", 'w') as storage_file:
            sys.stdout = storage_file
            print ('what')
    sys.stdout = stdout
    print('Completed Global variables creation')
```

Answer (score 0):

you're closing the file but you are not changing sys.stdout back to it's original value; so this line `print('Completed Global variables creation')` is trying to print in storage_file, which is a closed file descriptor.

something like this should work. you can also save in a variable the original value o `sys.stdout` and then change it back instead of accessing `sys.__stdout__`

```
  import sys
  print('###################################Genarating Global    Variables##########################')
  storage_file = open("Storage-output.txt", 'w')
  sys.stdout = storage_file
  print ('what')
  storage_file.close()
  sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__  # return to its original value as stated in https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__
  print('Completed Global variables creation')
```